# Ionic Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, ionic5

I'm getting property 'subscribe' does not exist of type 'void'

In my account.page.ts, I have the following. (This is where is error is)

```
  loadSpecialInfo(){
    this.authService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.data = res['msg'];
    });
  }
```

In my authService.ts file, I have the following.

```
getData(){
  this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(val => {
    const headers = { 'X-Access-Token': val, 'My-Custom-Header': 'foobar' }
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/protected', { headers }).pipe (
      catchError(e => {
        let status = e.status;
        if (status === 401) {
          this.showAlert('You are not authorized');
          this.logout();
        }
        throw new Error(e);
      })
    )
  })
}
```

Any help given will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `getData` does not return anything. Make it return `this.storage....` then use `getData().then(s=> s.subscribe....`

Comment: `this.http.get` should be out of `this.storage..` and return it.

Comment: There is no return in your service

Comment: Hi. I need the value from the storage and pass it over to the http.get. If I moved it out of storage.get, I will not have the value to be included in the http headers. I have also tried  return this.storage.get ....(same error)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the common cases of combining promises and observables. There are multiple ways to fix it. One way would be to use RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) to convert the promise to an observable and [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to map and return the HTTP request. Try the following

```js
import { from, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, throwError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData(){
  return from(this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY)).pipe(
    switchMap(val => {
      const headers = { 'X-Access-Token': val, 'My-Custom-Header': 'foobar' }
      return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/protected', { headers }).pipe(
        catchError(e => {
          let status = e.status;
          if (status === 401) {
            this.showAlert('You are not authorized');
            this.logout();
          }
          return throwError(e);        // <-- you could also use `throwError` here
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael D. Thanks a lot. I've been wasting a lot of time trying to get it working. Problem is I don't know when is it a promise and/or observable. I search a bit on that to understand more. Thanks again. It solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Would be great if you accepted the answer.